# Sql query to delete rows for a specific condtion

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to write query for the following

mysql db has two columns with data as follows

```
no id
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
3   5
3   6
4   7
5   8
```

i need to write query for the following condtion

when "no" repeats, delete all those rows from db where "no" is same and "id" > min of id for that "no"

```
expected output for the above table
no id
1   1
2   4 
3   5
4   7
5   8
```

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  no, MIN(ID) min_ID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY no
        ) b ON a.no = b.no AND
                a.id = b.min_ID
WHERE   b.no IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c17bd/1)

The other way,

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN tableName b 
        ON a.no = b.no
WHERE   a.id > b.id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bd7d/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(id) FROM tableName GROUP BY no
)
```

HTH